# Why does Float column in Oracle gets automatically rounded-off?

Tags: oracle, floating-point, type-conversion

Why a column with datatype as Float defined in Oracle gets automatically rounded off?

Column is created as FLOAT(5). 
"TRK_TARE" FLOAT(5)

Example (Value Entered -> Final Value Retained) -:

```
     123 -> 120
    1237 -> 1200    
   12347 -> 12000  
  123457 -> 120000  
 1234567 -> 1200000 
12345678 -> 12000000
```

What is the difference between FLOAT & NUMBER.

Note : No modification on Trigger is present on this columns

Comment: The difference between FLOAT and NUMBER is that NUMBER is what you should use in almost all cases in Oracle (not necessarily in any other languages or DB products), and FLOAT is the data type you should use only if you have a very good reason to do so. There are other answers as well, but this is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [the precision of a FLOAT is measured in binary digits](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm), from the docs:

> A subtype of the NUMBER data type having precision p. A FLOAT value is represented internally as NUMBER. The precision p can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A FLOAT value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

If I cast 123 as a `FLOAT(5)` I get the same answer:

```
SQL> select cast(123 as float(5)) from dual;

CAST(123ASFLOAT(5))
-------------------
                120
```

However, when casting as a `FLOAT(7)` the result is 123

```
SQL> select cast(123 as float(7)) from dual;

CAST(123ASFLOAT(7))
-------------------
                123
```

In general, unless there is a reason for specifying a precision, don't.

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong with the type declaration. I recommend to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) chapter of the Oracle Documentation (under "Float Datatype" part).

In this example, the `float` value returned cannot exceed **5 binary digits**. The largest decimal number that can be represented by 5 binary digits is 31. In your examples the value exceeds 31. 
Therefore, the `float` value must be truncated so that its significant digits do not require more than 5 binary digits. For example 123 is rounded to 120, which has only two significant decimal digits, requiring only 4 binary digits.

> Oracle Database uses the Oracle FLOAT datatype internally when
>   converting ANSI FLOAT data. Oracle FLOAT is available for you to use,
>   but Oracle recommends that you use
>   the BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE datatypes instead, as they are more
>   robust. Refer to ["Floating-Point Numbers"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i140176) for more information.

Comment: Could you explain why in this code snippet: `create table xx( x float(5) ); insert into xx select level from dual connect by level <= 200;  select * from xx;` values that exceed 31 are not truncated ? Values from 1 to 100 are not truncated, only values greater than 100 are truncated.